# I am trying to fetch data from 3 tables of a database, and it is not giving me desired results

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have a music db having 3 tables in it "Songs", "Comments" , "Rating". What I'm trying to do is to fetch all names of songs along with their average rating, and the last comment posted about it. I am trying following query but it returns just one row... 

`select s.name as Name, round(avg(r.score),2) as Rating, c.comment as Comment
from songs s , ratings r, comments c
where s.id = r.songId And s.id = c.songId And c.id = (select id from comments order by id DESC LIMIT 1)
group by s.id`

Comment: And c.id = (select id from comments order by id DESC LIMIT 1)    => limits the entire result to the id returned inside that subquery.

Comment: select s.name as Name, round(avg(r.score),2) as Rating, c.comment as Comment
from songs s , ratings r, (select id, comment from comments order by id DESC LIMIT 1) c
where s.id = r.songId And s.id = c.songId  
group by s.id